# Pandas - row to new column by value merging by index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to manipulate some data in pandas so that it's compatible with an existing piece of software, the operation to perform would be similar to this:

original dataframe:

```
    some_data   language    spelling
1   12          french      un
1   12          english     one
1   12          spanish     uno
2   52          french      deux
2   52          english     two
2   52          spanish     dos
```

target dataframe:

```
    some_data   lang_en   lang_fr   lang_sp
1   12          one       un        uno
2   52          two       deux      dos
```

So it will merge the indexes and reorder some of the rows to show it in a column, while keeping any supplementary column data.

All the columns that are not to be 'spitted' (some_data, in this example) contain duplicate data across a single index, many such columns exist in the real data.

I would definitely be able to do it by looping on the dataframe, but am trying to figure out if it's possible to do this entirely with pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.set_index(['some_data','language'])['spelling']\
  .unstack()\
  .rename(columns=lambda x: 'lang_' + x[:2])\
  .rename_axis([None], axis=1)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   some_data lang_en lang_fr lang_sp
0         12     one      un     uno
1         52     two    deux     dos
```